# Detach and Attach div as a dialog in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a div with some id that contains some buttons/labels. Its a container itself. I want to have a button that when user clicks on the button a dialog has to appear with the same div but the div has to disappear from the page. So when Detach button is clicked a dialog appears with that div and button changes into Attach. When attach is clicked dialog disappears and regular div appears on the page.

This is what i tried so far, it works only when Detach is clicked, if Attach is clicked dialog closes but regular div does not show up.

```
   $(document).on('click', '#detach', function() {
      var button = $(this).text();
          if (button == 'Detach') {
           $('.search_div_box').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 700 });
           $('.search_div_box').dialog('open');
              $(this).html('Attach');
          } else if (button == 'Attach') {
             $('.search_div_box').dialog('close');
             $(this).html('Detach');
          }

      });
```

i know im missing a code in Attach part it only closes the dialog but i tried various things like appending to body again the div and so on but didnt work. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [$.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a duplicate of the `div` and then show/hide it along with the dialog like this:

```
var $original = $('.search_div_box');
var $clone = $('.search_div_box').clone();
    $clone.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
        });

$(document).on('click', '#detach', function() {
    var button = $(this).text();

    if (button == 'Detach') {
        $original.hide();
        $clone.dialog('open');

        $(this).html('Attach');
    } else if (button == 'Attach') {
        $original.show();
        $clone.dialog('close');

        $(this).html('Detach');
    }
});​
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4U9G/2/)

Comment: that works great and thank you. When it clones it, it does not clone the data generated by PHP and JQUERY. I have little box that shows total count of something and when detached dialog total shows 0 when attached total shows 185

Comment: never mind i added  $clone.html($original.html()); inside Detach part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
<button id="button">Attach</button>
```

javascript (jquery):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var button = $(this).html();
    if (button === "Attach") {
        $('.search_div_box').dialog('close');
        $(this).html('Detach');
    }
    else {
        $('.search_div_box').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 700 });
        $('.search_div_box').dialog('open');
        $(this).html('Attach');
    }
});
```

That should work :)

Comment: i dont see how is that different from my code you just switched up the if/else. I tried it anyways and it does exactly samething as my code. On Detach click it shows up dialog with div and on Attach click dialog dissapears but div is not visible on the page either. I want that div to show on page once Attach is clicked

Comment: It doesnt make sense to close a dialog and wanting it to still be visible ... A dialog is a seperate window that you can popup and close.

Comment: i dont want a dialog to be visible i want the content of the dialog to show on the page as it was before detaching it. Before detaching div shows on page on right corner when detach clicked div disappears and shows in dialog when attaching it dialog disappears and on the right corner is nothing to show

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<button class="content detach"></button>
```

CSS

```
.content.detach:after {
   content: "Detach";
}
.content.attach:after {
   content: "Attach";
}
```

JS

```
    $('.search_div_box').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 700 });
$(".content, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").on("click", function(){
    if ($(".content").hasClass("detach")) {

        $('.search_div_box').dialog('open');
    } else {
        $('.search_div_box').dialog('close');
    }

    $(".content").toggleClass("detach attach");
});
```

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n8Mbz/

Comment: again that does samething as my code. On detach it does show a dialog with the div inside, but when attach is clicked dialog dissapears and div as well. I want when attach is clicked that div to be attached to the page or to show anywhere on the page.