# Restore jQuery dialog element to initial size/position on "destroy"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

An example is better than 1000 words:

http://jsfiddle.net/GF7KF/4/

There is a blue `div`. If you click the 'Open it!' button, that `div` is opened in a jquery ui dialog. How can I do that when I close the dialog the `div` returns to its initial position? Is there an easy way or I have to do some code to remember manually it for each concrete situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a placeholder element inside the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/zjMvS/1/

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <span id="dialog"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var d = $('span#dialog');
$('.open-dialog').click(function() {
    d.dialog({
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton, but this is not opening the div, but the span, so the `p` inside the `div` (the `Hello!` text) is not showed in the dialog.

Comment: @cram1010 I think I misunderstood. What's the goal? Why would you open a dialog of something already shown on the screen? Normally dialog contents are hidden/shown, when you close a dialog (different than destroy, btw), you hide the DOM element with the dialog's content. But you say you don't want to hide the div? What's the point?

Comment: Well, I'm working in some modal form. When the page is loaded, only first field is showed (the rest are hidden by jQuery), and there is one "Edit" button. When this is clicked, I want the whole form to be opened and showed in the dialog. When the dialog is closed, I want the whole form to return to its initial position, and hide again all fields but first with jQuery.

Comment: @cram1010 Then you'll probably need to do something slightly different, because when you close a dialog, its content is hidden. There are any number of ways around the issue, I guess.

Comment: Yeah @DaveNewton, I think you are right. I was taking a wrong approximation, I should use something that leave the DOM in place. Thanks for make me thinking :)

Comment: This solution did the trick : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673935/div-disappears-from-original-place-after-closing-the-dialog